# SQL error on (seemingly) simple query

Tags: sql

```
select distinct 
    assignedTo, 
    alert_id, 
    insert_date_time, 
    alert_status_id, 
    alert_action_id, 
    alert_call_reason_id, 
    target_date  
from Case_Management.AlertDetail
```

Works fine.

```
select distinct 
    assignedTo, 
    alert_id, 
    max(insert_date_time), 
    alert_status_id, 
    alert_action_id, 
    alert_call_reason_id, 
    target_date  
from Case_Management.AlertDetail
```

Returns the error Column 'Case_Management.AlertDetail.assignedTo' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I'm stumped.

Comment: You're using an aggregate function (`MAX`) without a `GROUP BY` for the remaining fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is pretty clear, add the columns that are not in an aggregate function to a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
select 
    assignedTo, 
    alert_id, 
    max(insert_date_time), 
    alert_status_id, 
    alert_action_id, 
    alert_call_reason_id, 
    target_date  
from Case_Management.AlertDetail 
GROUP BY assignedTo, 
         alert_id,
         alert_status_id, 
         alert_action_id,
         alert_call_reason_id, 
         target_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a group by clause in the 2nd query because you have an aggregate.  The aggregate is

```
max(insert_date_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about what you want to achieve. You want to select some records but one of the columns is not the content of the regular record but a summaration of all columns. You cant mix that.

You need to group your data to achieve that or use a subselect.